# Saving a selected folder using DirectoryChooser into my database

Tags: java

I am developing an app which requires me to select a folder from my system and save it to my database. I have been able to select the folder using `DirectoryChooser`, but I'm stuck saving the chosen folder to my database.

This code is where I stopped and I want to save all the contents of the selected folder to my database:

```
private void upload1(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
    final DirectoryChooser dirchooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    Stage stage = (Stage) rootPane.getScene().getWindow();
    File file = dirchooser.showDialog(stage);

    if (file != null) {
        path1.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so, what is the problem you're facing with the code?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to save to your database? The **filename** of the chosen folder? Or the **contents of all the files** contained in the folder?

Comment: this code is where i stopped and i want to save all the contents of the selected folder to my database

Comment: OK, then.  You've got the `File` object for the folder.  You can use `file.listFiles` to obtain an array of `File` objects for all the files in the folder.  There rest depends on what sort of data is in the files and how that data will be represented in your database.